# Capturing unexpected termination in PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest

I'm using CodeIgniter to host a RESTful API and I'd like to capture any API response that does not return an expected status code.  This is probably most easily explained with an example.  In general, my code looks like this:

```
function post_comment()
{
     $comment = $_POST['comment'];
     $result = do_something_with_comment($comment);

     if ($result === true)
     {
         return_json_response(200, 'OK!');
     }
     else
     {
         return_json_response(400, 'Something terrible happened...');
     }
}
```

Returning either a 200 or 400 is perfectly valid.  My problem is: how to capture errors when do_something_with_comment() has a fatal error, or if I leave a print debug inside of do_something_with_comment().  In the former case, I'll never reach return_json_response().  In the latter case, I'll reach it, but the screen debug will corrupt the JSON response.

Is there any way to create a generic wrapper around this to capture any unexpected output or termination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you could:

Use exception /exception handling as much as possible

Register a custom errorhandler that transforms PHP errors into exceptions, for instance put this in top of your config/config.php

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno))
    {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    log_message('error', "$errstr @$errfile::$errline($errno)" );
    throw new ErrorException( $errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline );
}
set_error_handler("my_error_handler");
```

Register an uncaught exception handler, put something like this in your config/config.php

```
function my_exception_handler($exception)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($exception);
    echo '</pre>';
    header( "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error" );
}
set_exception_handler("my_exception_handler");
```

**EDIT**

Set a termination handler:

```
function my_fatal_handler()
{
    $errfile = "unknown file";
    $errstr  = "Fatal error";
    $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
    $errline = 0;
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ( $error !== NULL )
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($error);
        echo '</pre>';
        header( "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error" );
    }
}
register_shutdown_function("my_fatal_handler");
```

Set a custom assert handler that converts asserts into exceptions, put something like this in your config/config.php:

```
function my_assert_handler($file, $line, $code)
{
    log_message('debug', "assertion failed @$file::$line($code)" );
    throw new Exception( "assertion failed @$file::$line($code)" );
}
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE,     1);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING,    0);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL,       0);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'my_assert_handler');
```

Then, **and this is your answer**, use wrappers like this in your controllers

```
public function controller_method( )
{
    try
    {
        // normal flow
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        log_message( 'error', $e->getMessage( ) . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() );
        // on error
    }
}
```

You can tune and customize the whole thing to your likings!

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You will also need to intercept the CI show_error method. Place this in application/core/MY_exceptions.php:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    function show_error($heading, $message, $template = 'error_general', $status_code = 500)
    {
        log_message( 'debug', print_r( $message, TRUE ) );
        throw new Exception(is_array($message) ? $message[1] : $message, $status_code );
    }
}
```

And leave in application/config/database.php this setting on FALSE to have database errors converted into exceptions.

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

CI has a few (very) weak points, such as exception-handling but this will go a long way correcting that.

Comment: Wow, that's far more brilliant than I expected.  :)  I will give all of those methods a try.  In general my code has decent error handling, but I can't yet go to sleep at night knowing that everything is captured properly.  Thanks Patrick!

Comment: Well, to do it completely right, you will have to catch the CI-DB errors also. I will edit the answer and add that too!

Comment: I added your code as-is and it worked *perfectly* out of the box.  :)  My DB error now returns as a status 400 via my API. (Not that I'd want my end-consumer to see that, but it's a start)  Now I just need to better understand what you gave me and customize it.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: One quick question: Where does log_message() write its data to?  I'm assuming the path is in one of the config files?  EDIT  Disregard.  It is in config.php.  Just a matter of making the log directory writable.

Comment: Last question: Do you know a safe way to extend log_message()?  I'd like it to email me the full exception if the type is an "error".  In general I want to know about errors and fix them immediately, so I'm ok with being spammed.

Comment: Log_message writes to /application/logs. To extend you should write your own MY_Log.php class in /application/libraries and override the write_log() method.

Comment: I actually tried overwriting write_log(), but I don't think MY_Log.php is overwriting it.  (I added a die() statement in my write_log() and it never hit, but it does if I move it into Log.php's write_log())  I took a look at core/Common's log_message() method, and I don't think it is designed to consider my extended class.  I don't think I can extend core/Common either.  Any recommendations aside from hacking the CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: Not that I can think of :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a function [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) within which you can set your own closing handler for every script. Just do what you need there.

BTW: Make your scripts as bullet-proof as you can. Your scripts shouldn't ever have fatal errors, segfaults, or such runtime errors. Any response, even invalid for client is valid in context of request handling. I'd encourage you to take a look at Symfony2 framework or simply at its [HttpKernel](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel) / HttpFoundation components as they quite nicely wrap this process in a friendly interface.

Comment: That's a good idea - I'll give that a try as well!  I've looked at Symfony and I think the learning curve and overhead is a bit too steep for me right now.  I've already invested a year into CodeIgniter.  :)