# Custom handling of DB errors with Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I encountered a problem where my ci_sessions table had become corrupt and the error + raw SQL was displayed on the website.

IF I set db_debug to false then I get a blank screen with a 200 response header. How can I override this to show a friendly page?

Comment: CI is not very strong on error-handling. Maybe this general answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080719/capturing-unexpected-termination-in-php-codeigniter/15085880#15085880

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend that you turn `db_debug` to `false`, since (as you said) it shows raw SQL data and is not really neat in terms of security.

That said, you can view any error messages of your SQL using `$this->db->_error_message()` .

Use that as a IF condition to show some other page, of do anything else.

```
$this->db->get("any table"); // this is where your original db statement goes
if ($this->db->_error_message()) {
    return false;  // you can do this, or show another view, or anything
}
```

NOTE: `$this->db->_error_message()` is not an officially supported function, and may change in future versions of CI. So just be careful there.